# Persistent web client storage

Tags: cookies, browser, persistence

What are, today, the solutions for persistent storage on web client side ?
(I don't think about servers, only client side)

We have the old and very limited "cookies", and ??

Right, I've seen this
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

But is it really "scalable" ?
Do you know apps/sites which are using one of them ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), Chapter 7, Local Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but things have moved on since then.

Today, all modern browsers support HTML5 Web Storage. This is designed to be a more resilient solution than cookies, which was never meant for this kind of thing.

The problems with cookies include:

- A limit to the amount of data which can be stored per site and overall
- An unfriendly API
- Cookies are always sent back to the server under the impression that that’s where they came from, even if they were created by JavaScript.

Web Storage has more capacity (a few megabytes, depending) and is easier to work with.

You can learn more about Web Storage at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API